# How to add/post artilcle in joomla with xmlrpc

Tags: php, joomla2.5

How to i add a article in joomla using php from outside Joomla admin panel, like xmlrpc in wordpress

Comment: You can try this one: http://extensions.hoicoimasti.com/products/joomla-extensions/3-joomla-api-for-mobile-apps-android,-iphone-ipad-external-site.html

Comment: thanks for suggestion , but can u  tell how to add new article in joomla .... from out side of joomla

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will be help full for you.

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_implement_XML-RPC_in_a_component

You also can search and use any 3rd party extension for this. Please check this link http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/blogging-xmlrpc-for-joomla, if it can be help full  according to your requirement.

Comment: Please include significant information directly in your answer.